# Windows service split to multiple services to reduce load on it, but all services use a common dll for processing. Does it help reduce load?

Tags: c#, windows-services, split, load-balancing

I'm trying to reduce load on a windows service by splitting the load pie into multiple services, on the same server box.
But each of the service uses the same dll, shared between all the 5 windows service, to perform the underlying processing. 
Would this model of distribution of load / load-balancing make sense? 
Would I be better off, if I deploy each service with its own processor.dll?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if sharing a dll would affect the load balancing of the app. as in, "am I really running two instances if I'm sharing the dll?"

In that case no it will not, there is no difference if both processes are using the exact same folder/dll or even exe file. there is no need to deploy different files for each service.

Every time you start the service, I'm assuming windows service, a new process is created in complete isolation.

Answer (score 0):

The DLL will certainly help you to save some physical memory (especially if it's a large DLL). And of course disk space.

It may be more efficient to make a single multi-threaded service, then you will able to load several CPU cores while using common RAM structures.